# Reading file from G Drive via Apache Beam

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to fetch file from Google Drive using Apache Beam. I tried,

```
filenames = ['https://drive.google.com/file/d/<file_id>']
with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
    lines = (pipeline | beam.Create(filenames))
print(lines)
```

This returns a string like `PCollection[[19]: Create/Map(decode).None]`

I need to read a file from Google Drive and write it into GCS bucket. How can I read a file form G Drive from Apache beam?

Comment: Airflow has an operator to support this use case: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/transfer/gdrive_to_gcs.html

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t have complex transformations to apply, I thinks it’s better to not use `Beam` in this case.

- Solution 1 :

You can instead use `Google Collab` (Juypiter Notebook on Google servers), mount your gDrive and use the gCloud CLI to copy files.

You can check the following links :

[google-drive-to-gcs](https://philipplies.medium.com/transferring-data-from-google-drive-to-google-cloud-storage-using-google-colab-96e088a8c041)

[stackoverflow-copy-file-from-google-drive-to-gcs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48122091/copy-file-from-google-drive-to-google-cloud-storage-within-google)

- Solution 2

You can also use APIs to retrieve files from `Google Drive` and copy them to `Cloud Storage`.

You can for example develop a `Python` script using `Python` Google clients and the following packages :

```
google-api-python-client 
google-auth-httplib2 
google-auth-oauthlib 
google-cloud-storage
```

This [article](https://servian.dev/automate-data-ingestion-from-google-drive-to-google-cloud-storage-879d8ad6def) shows an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Beam for this, you would could write a function

```
def read_from_gdrive_and_yield_records(path):
    ...
```

and then use it like

```
filenames = ['https://drive.google.com/file/d/<file_id>']
with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
    paths = pipeline | beam.Create(filenames)
    records = paths | beam.FlatMap(read_from_gdrive_and_emit_records)
    records | beam.io.WriteToText('gs://...')
```

Though as mentioned, unless you have a lot of files, this may be overkill.